# boost::lockfree::spsc_queue and boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-circularbuffer

I'm would like to receive directly into a `boost::lockfree:spsc_queue` (or, alternatively, a `boost::circular_buffer`) from a `boost::asio::async_read` call. Looks like I need to write a wrapper to make the spsc_queue a `MutableBuffer`.

Can anyone share some guidance on if this is possible, and how to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: `boost::lockfree:spsc_queue` is not a suitable buffer for received bytes.

Comment: thanks for heads up.  is `boost::circular_buffer` a suitable buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Each receive buffer must be contiguous when using `asio`.

Since `boost::circular_buffer` is not contiguous it is rather inconvenient to use as a byte buffer. Still, though, you can present it to `asio` as 2 buffers with [scatter-gather I/O](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o).

An efficient and convenient circular buffer for I/O is a region of memory pages mapped twice without any padding between them. This way you can read into your circular buffer with one `read` syscall, without having to use scatter-gather I/O and without having to deal with buffer discontinuity when parsing/reading its contents.